# Combining Text from a table into a blob

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my code I have a blob of data that I am separating out into a table to make it look more presentable. This is working fine and it's pretty awesome.

However, I'm having an issue putting the data back together so I can store it back as that unsightly blob because I cannot change any of the backend.

I've tried just a simple concatenation, but it's printing the classes in separate rows when they need to be bunched back together. Any ideas?

```
<table class="table" id="DataTables_Table_5">
  <thead style="display:none;">
    <tr role="row">
      <th name="date" scope="col" class="sorting_disabled commentDate" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px;">Invalid date</th>
      <th name="user" scope="col" class="sorting_disabled commentUser" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px;">UserName</th>
      <th name="comment" scope="col" class="sorting_disabled commentComment" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px;">Comment</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td class=" commentDate">Fr 01 12, 2017</td>
      <td class=" commentUser">Demo</td>
      <td class=" commentComment">skvbgskjhbgswdjefv</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td class=" commentDate">Mo 04 12, 2017</td>
      <td class=" commentUser">DEMO</td>
      <td class=" commentComment">This issvgswrgwrgwrgwrg</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td class=" commentDate">Mo 04 12, 2017</td>
      <td class=" commentUser">DEMOoooo</td>
      <td class=" commentComment">Super long. Super aewsome. Super long. Super aewsome. Super long. Super aewsome. Super long. Super aewsome. Super long. Super aewsome. Super long. Super aewsome. Super long. Super aewsome. Super long. Super aewsome. Super long. Super aewsome. Super long. Super aewsome. Super long. Super aewsome. Super long. Super aewsome. </td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td class=" commentDate">Mo 04 12, 2017</td>
      <td class=" commentUser">DEMO DEMO</td>
      <td class=" commentComment">This is a short comment after the super long comment</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and the js I have tried looks like this

```
$(".commentDate").text()+ '\n' + $(".commentUser").text() + '\n\n' + $(".commentComment").text()+ '\n\n'
```

https://www.bootply.com/8sDFSzV22Y

Comment: You forgot to include jQuery in your fiddle

Comment: AH I hate that about fiddles. I put in a bootply instead

Answer (score 1):

You need to read each row and then read each cell of each row to concatenate.

```js
var rows = document.querySelectorAll( '#DataTables_Table_5 tr' );
var lines = [];

// Read each row
for ( var i = 0; i < rows.length; ++i ) {
  var r = rows[ i ];
  // Read each cell
  var cells = [].slice.call( r.querySelectorAll( 'td, th' ) )
    .map( function( c ) { return c.innerText } );
  // Collect concatenated cells
  lines.push( cells.join( ',' ) );
}

console.log( lines.join( '\n\n' ) );
```

```html
<table class="table" id="DataTables_Table_5">
  <thead style="display:none;">
    <tr role="row">
      <th name="date" scope="col" class="sorting_disabled commentDate" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px;">Invalid date</th>
      <th name="user" scope="col" class="sorting_disabled commentUser" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px;">UserName</th>
      <th name="comment" scope="col" class="sorting_disabled commentComment" rowspan="1" colspan="1" style="width: 0px;">Comment</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td class=" commentDate">Fr 01 12, 2017</td>
      <td class=" commentUser">Demo</td>
      <td class=" commentComment">skvbgskjhbgswdjefv</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td class=" commentDate">Mo 04 12, 2017</td>
      <td class=" commentUser">DEMO</td>
      <td class=" commentComment">This issvgswrgwrgwrgwrg</td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="odd">
      <td class=" commentDate">Mo 04 12, 2017</td>
      <td class=" commentUser">DEMOoooo</td>
      <td class=" commentComment">Super long. Super aewsome. Super long. Super aewsome. Super long. Super aewsome. Super long. Super aewsome. Super long. Super aewsome. Super long. Super aewsome. Super long. Super aewsome. Super long. Super aewsome. Super long. Super aewsome. Super long. Super aewsome. Super long. Super aewsome. Super long. Super aewsome. </td>
    </tr>
    <tr role="row" class="even">
      <td class=" commentDate">Mo 04 12, 2017</td>
      <td class=" commentUser">DEMO DEMO</td>
      <td class=" commentComment">This is a short comment after the super long comment</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is there a way not to select all the tr's on the page? What if there are multiple tables?

Comment: I just updated my answer. You can add the id or the class name of the table to the selector.

Comment: This works in Chrome, but does not work in ie. Ie does not like contents nor the for loop

Comment: IE doesn't support for-of-loop syntax, nor does it support constants and arrow functions. It is common practice to use [babel](https://babeljs.io/) to transpile your code back to ES5 or even ES3. But it was pretty simple to convert it (as you can see in my updated answer), so that even IE11 supports this solution.